# Android non-existing files found when loading cursor from URI /external/video/media

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

Hi guys I'm working on an android video sharing app. I need to load video files from the device and display their thumbnails in a GridView. This is how I do it, using a Cursor. The code below works fine but quite often I found non-existing video files returned by the cursor showing up. Those are usually video files I deleted moments ago. They will disappear after I reboot my device.

I noticed the same problem in google's Photos app, i.e. the one coming with Google+ app. Same behaviour.

I know that I can put String[] where and String[] args inside the constructor of CursorLoader but I don't know how I can check whether a given file path really exists in the query.

Has anyone encountered the same situation? Thanks for any help.

```
String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.LONGITUDE,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.LATITUDE,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED
    };

    Cursor videoCursor = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
            null, null, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC"
            ).loadInBackground();
```

Comment: any solution for this?? i face the same problem  now.